# Reducing hight of superscript in HTML by css

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a wordpress installation and all the superscripts come out to high:

[image]

Is there a way to get the footnote and other material in `<sup></sup>` down? By some CCS I could add to the page? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the default `vertical-align: sup;` you could change it to top and adjust the position with top and minus value;

```css
sup { 
    vertical-align: top; 
    position: relative;
    top:  -0.2em; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Don't know which of the answers is better.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of **sup** you can use **sub**. But if you can't change it to a , try to add a position absolute and some margin top

```
// html
<p>Footnote<sup>1</sup></p>

// styles
p sup {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```